# subprocess library didn't work correctly for `py setup.py py2exe` command

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I tried to write a code that can execute python codes easily.

but when I used `subprocess` library such:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.Popen("py setup.py install", shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
print(subprocess.Popen("py setup.py py2exe", shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```

I saw just this result

```
b''
```

please help me please

Comment: Why are you printing the subprocesses? Suggest taking a look at the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: @oystein-hr I printing `subprocess.Popen(...).stdout.read()` I saw the page many many time but I still can't use `subprocess` for my project :(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the commands you are trying to run are producing a `stderr`, which your code does not display. It is possible to send the `stderr` messages to `stdout` if you don't want to handle it separately.

I'll use a different command in the subprocess that is relatively safe. And I will break it up a little instead of having one long line.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("python filedoesntexist",
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

See that I added the parameter `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, this sends all the error messages to `stdout`. The `subprocess` tries to run `"python filedoesntexist"` and since `filedoesntexist` is a file that doesn't exists, it will `print` this message:

```
b"python: can't open file 'filedoesntexist': [Errno 2] No such file or directory\n"
```

But you might just want to get the `string` instead of `bytes`, and you can add the parameter `universal_newlines=True` like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("python filedoesntexist",
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                     universal_newlines=True)
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Now it prints just the `string` like this:

```
python: can't open file 'filedoesntexist': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

For additional information, visit the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

---

*Edit*

The documentation recommends using `run()`, which can be done like this (*updated after comments from J.F. Sebastian*) :

```
subprocess.run(["python", "filedoesntexist"])
```

If you need to handle `stdout` in some way, add parameters described earlier in the `Popen` examples.

Comment: (1) there is no reason to use `shell=True` here. (2) OP probably wants `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'setup.py', 'py2exe'])` (the output is not used).

Comment: (1) If I don't have `shell=True`, it won't run. (2) `subprocess.check_call()` has been replaced by `subprocess.run()` in 3.5 according to the documentation. (3) If I edit the `subprocess.run()` example a little I can remove `shell=True` :)

Comment: (1) the code example in my comment shows how to avoid `shell=True` (2) `subprocess.run()` is recommended on Python 3.5+. It doesn't mean that `check_call()` is deprecated (replaced). Anyway, the point is that you don't need to capture the output at all (if all you do is print it back)

Comment: Cool. Updated the `run()` example. Not sure if the OP wants to handle `stdout`, assumed OP wanted to since OP was printing them.